# Movimento de pagina HTML

Tags: html, css

Quando clico em uma âncora como `<a href="#um_id">clique aqui</a>`, que tem um #ID no href, ele tem como default movimentar até a parte que tem esse id como marcador.

Como eu desabitaria esse comportamento?

Comment: E o que pretende fazer no clique da âncora? Âncoras foram feitas para navegação, se a ideia é executar alguma função javascript no clique, utilize um botão e, por padrão, não terá o problema citado.

Comment: Vc quer quebrar a ancora? Basta colocar no href do link um id que não existe, tipo #! Por exemplo, ou então retira o iD da tag html do elemento . sua pergunta não ficou muito clara.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode desativar a ação padrão de uma âncora (seja para o próprio documento ou um link normal) de duas maneiras. Meus exemplos irão afetar todas as âncoras da página, cabe a você adaptar os seletores à sua necessidade.

## Com CSS

```
a { pointer-events: none; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bfavaretto/yu7rL2n4/

## Com JS

```
const stopClick = (e) => e.preventDefault()
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach( a => a.addEventListener('click', stopClick, false));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bfavaretto/y2hqpbtf/